# Snowflake removing backslashes during Procedure compilation?

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For some reason Snowflake is removing backslashes from my regex function, but only when I put the function in between the "$$" when creating a Javascript procedure.

For context here is my Regex Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "REGEX_REPLACE_ME"("SUBJECT" VARCHAR(16777216), "PATTERN" VARCHAR(16777216), "REPLACEMENT" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS '
  
    const p = SUBJECT;
    let regex = new RegExp(PATTERN, ''i'') 
    return p.replace(regex, REPLACEMENT);
  ';
```

When I run it simply in SQL, it works; it will change "APPLE.com" to "APPLE".

```sql
SELECT REXP_REPLACE_ME('APPLE.COM','\\.[A-Z]{2,3}',' ') -- the regex pattern \\.[A-Z]{2,3} is meant to remove domains i.e. ".com",".org", etc..
```

However, when I run it within $$ of a stored procedure, it removes the backslashes from my regex pattern and consequently changing the regex pattern completely.

My regex changes from `\\.[A-Z]{2,3}` to ->  `.[A-Z]{2,3}`

```sql
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TESTING_FUNC_1_THIS_CAN_BE_DELETED()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$

var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
`
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Database.Schema.Table AS

    SELECT REXP_REPLACE_ME('APPLE.COM','\\.[A-Z]{2,3}',' ')  as column_cleaned
 --   ,REXP_REPLACE_ME_WTF('APPLE.COM','\\.[A-Z]{2,3}',' ') AS WHAT_PATTERN_IS_BEING_OUTPUTTED -- function logic in code block below
    
`
                            } );
  $$;

call TESTING_FUNC_1_THIS_CAN_BE_DELETED();

select * from Database.Schema.Table
```

Scratching my head here, I created this function to show what pattern it was outputting and this is how I came to the conclusion (I can be wrong here..) that when Snowflake is compiling it's removing the backslash...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "REXP_REPLACE_ME_WTF"("SUBJECT" VARCHAR(16777216), "PATTERN" VARCHAR(16777216), "REPLACEMENT" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS '
  
    const p = SUBJECT;
    let regex = new RegExp(PATTERN, ''i'');
    //return p.replace(regex, REPLACEMENT);
    return PATTERN;
  ';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Snowflake SQL uses \ as an escape character, so to represent a backslash in Snowflake SQL you have to use `\\`.

JavaScript also uses \ as an escape character, so to represent a backslash in JavaScript you also have to use `\\`

If you want to represent a single backslash in Snowflake SQL through JavaScript, you have to send 2 x 2 = 4 backslashes `\\\\`

Answer (score 3):

Probably something to do with escape characters etc

Try wrapping your SQL statement in backticks instead of single quotes: ``

Comment: Hmm I believe I'm using backticks in the example?

Comment: Sorry, you are indeed. Didn't spot them! Still think it is something to do with them being recognised as escape characters

Comment: Agreed, what's odd is that they are completely disappearing.