# How to Remove extra Backslash(\) in Snowflake using Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

using below select query i'm able to get the required result which removes extra slashes(3)

Answer:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('p\\\\','[\\|\\\\\|\\\|\\\\]','~'),'(~~|~)','\\\\');
```

while using the same query in StoredProcedure it throws an error:

```
Invalid regular expression: '[|\||\]', missing ]: [|\||\] At Statement.execute
```

Stored procedure code:

```
create or replace procedure back_slash(something varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
var command1=`select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('p\\\\','[\\|\\\\\|\\\|\\\\]','~'),'(~~|~)','\\\\')`;
var stmt1=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command1});
var rs1=stmt1.execute();
return 'successfully removed extra backslashs'
$$;
```

Comment: Backslash is an escape character in the SP so for every backslash, you need to add another to escape it

Answer (score 1):

So this:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('p\\\\','[\\|\\\\\|\\\|\\\\]','~'),'(~~|~)','\\\\');
```

returns:

```
p\
```

Change your stored procedure like this:

```
create or replace procedure back_slash(X1 varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
var command1="select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('p\\\\','[\\|\\\\\|\\\|\\\]','~'),'(~~|~)','\\\\')";
var stmt1=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command1});
var rs1=stmt1.execute();
rs1.next();
return rs1.getColumnValue(1);
$$;
```

and it will work. Observe I removed one **\** before **]**.

```
call back_slash('x');
```

result:

```
p\
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake SQL uses backslash as an escape character. To represent a single backslash in Snowflake SQL, you have to use two `\\`.

JavaScript also uses backslash as an escape character. To represent a single backslash in Snowflake SQL through JavaScript, you have to use 2x2=4 backslashes `\\\\`

Refer to this question and answer:

[Snowflake removing backslashes during Procedure compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485070/snowflake-removing-backslashes-during-procedure-compilation/69485518#69485518)

```
create or replace procedure back_slash(X1 varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
var command1="select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('p\\\\\\\\','[\\\\|\\\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\|\\\\\\\\]','~'),'(~~|~)','\\\\\\\\')";
var stmt1=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command1});
var rs1=stmt1.execute();
rs1.next();
return rs1.getColumnValue(1);
$$;

call back_slash('p\\\\');
```